# How to get from downtown Los Angeles to Disneyland and back without a car?

Tags: public-transport, los-angeles, disney

I'll be staying in downtown Los Angeles (near USC) soon and would like to plan a day out to Disneyland.  What good options are available for getting to Disneyland in the morning and back into downtown Los Angeles the same night, without a rental car?

Regarding rental vehicles, it's a combination of being young/not wanting to drive in a foreign country with different road rules/not liking the thought of driving in LA traffic that's putting me off it.  I understand Los Angeles doesn't have a very good reputation for public transport, but what options are there available for this trip?

Comment: Welcome to America, where decent public-transport services are for Commies (and parts of the east-coast).

Comment: Shuttle and taxi prices abound in this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/457/lax-to-anaheim-how-much-slower-is-the-super-shuttle-than-a-cab

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Metro Los Angeles](http://www.metro.net/) runs bus service to Disneyland in Anaheim from downtown Los Angeles.

You can take Bus **460** from 5th/Grand to Disneyland. For detailed schedule and stops, you can refer to the [timetable](http://www.metro.net/riding_metro/bus_overview/images/460.pdf) for 460.